# How do I hightlight the gutter in vim/nvim?

Tags: vimscript, neovim, colorscheme

As you can see in the image below, I have this weird highlight on my gutter. I'd be great if I could make that transparent. How can I do it?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I just found out that I can do `:higlight SignColumn guibg=#ff0000` to change the color to a solid one, but how would I make it transparent though?

Comment: try something like `:hi SignColumn guibg=NONE cterm=NONE term=NONE`

Comment: That works! I suggest you write it as an answer, I'll accept and up vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the Gutter Column transparent, I suggest you define it like the following:

```
:hi SignColumn guibg=NONE cterm=NONE term=NONE
```

This should come after any colorscheme command, so that it can override it, in case your colorscheme sets it. You can also place it into an `ColorScheme` autocommand, so that it will automatically override any colorscheme settings:

```
 au ColorScheme * :hi SignColumn guibg=NONE cterm=NONE term=NONE
```

Also, you may want to check where this was set previously, by using:

```
:verbose :hi SignColumn
```

which will tell you, in what configuration file this highlighting group was last set. It could also be set inside some plugin, that configure the sign column for you, in that case I'd recommend to check the documentation of the plugin how to configure the SignColumn properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Another option that works to me:**

```
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "SignColumn", { bg = "none"})
```